# Saving file everytime leaving insert mode in evil-mode

Tags: evil, saving

Is there a way that I can automatically save the file when leaving insert state to go to normal state with ESC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'evil-insert-state-exit-hook
          (lambda ()
            (call-interactively #'save-buffer)))
```

This will call the underlying command of `C-x C-s`. You can also call `evil-write` if you prefer the `:w` command behaviour

Comment: I tried adding this to my .emacs file, but it didn't seem to save when exited insert state with the ESC key. I'm still new to emacs so there could be something else that I am missing.

Comment: try it again now: I've edited my answer because I had made a wrong copy-paste

Comment: Works great! Thank you!